# If $D_{x_{0}}f$ is an isomorphism, there is $V_{x_{0}}$ s.t. $f(x) \neq f(x_{0})$ for $x \in V_{x_{0}}-\{x_{0}\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a continuous function, where $U$ is open. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable in $x_{0} \in U$ and $D_{x_{0}}f$ is an isomorphism. Show that there is a neighborhood $V_{x_{0}} \subset U$ of $x_{0}$ such that $f(x) \neq f(x_{0})$ for any $x \in V_{x_{0}}\setminus\{x_{0}\}$.

**My attempt** My idea is suppose that in each neighborhood $V_{x_{0}}$ of $x_{0}$ there is $x \in V_{x_{0}}\setminus\{x_{0}\}$ such that $f(x) = f(x_{0})$ for get a contradiction.

We can take a sequence $(x_{n})$ with $x_{n} \in B_{1/n}(x_{0})$ such that $x_{n} \to x_{0}$ and $f(x_{n}) = f(x_{0})$. Write $x_{n} = x_{0} + t_{n}h_{n}$ where $h_{n}$ is a unity vector. Note that
$$\Vert D_{x_{0}}f \Vert = \left\Vert \frac{f(x_{0}+t_{n}h_{n})-f(x_{0})}{t_{n}} - D_{x_{0}}f\right\Vert.$$

But, given $\epsilon > 0$,
$$\left\Vert \frac{f(x_{0}+t_{n}h_{n})-f(x_{0})}{t_{n}} - D_{x_{0}}f\right\Vert < \epsilon$$
whenever $|t_{n}| < \delta$. Since $x_{n} \to x_{0}$, we can take $\delta>0$ such that $|t_{n}| < \delta$ for all $n > n_{0}$ for some $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$. For this $\delta$, we get
$$\Vert D_{x_{0}}f \Vert < \epsilon,$$
then $D_{x_{0}}f$ cannot be an isomorphism.

---

Is this correct? The idea seems good to me, but I'm not sure about the details of the proof. Also, if its correct, I couldnt see where total continuity was necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation 
$$\| D_{x_0}f \|  = \left\| \frac{ f(x_0 + t_n h_n) - f(x_0)}{t_n} - D_{x_0}f \right\| $$
does not make sense to me.
  The quotient $\frac{f(x_0 + t_n h_n) - f(x_0)}{t_n}$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but $D_{x_0}f$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, so it is not meaningful to take their difference.  Moreover, if the LHS refers to a matrix norm, there is no hope in proving that $ \| D_{x_0}f \|$ vanishes. (A singular matrix may still have large norm.) Instead, if you want to prove that $D_{x_0}f$ is not an isomorphism under your assumption, you should show that there is some vector $h \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash\{0 \}$ so that $(D_{x_0}f) h$ (i.e. the vector multiplied by the matrix $D_{x_0}f$) is zero.

I think you should replace $D_{x_0}f$ by $(D_{x_0}f) h_n$ in all of the centered equations.  If you do so, your work shows that there is a sequence $\{ h_n \}$ of unit vectors so that $(D_{x_0}f) h_n \to 0$.  It follows by compactness of the unit ball that some subsequence $\{ h_{n_k} \}$ converges to a vector $h$.  I claim that $(D_{x_0}f) h = 0$.  Do you see why?

Comment: Perfect! The lack of $h_{n}$ was a notation error that I didn't realize, thank you for pointing it out! About the final conclusion, follows by continuity of $D_{x_{0}}f$?

Comment: Continuity of $Df$ is not needed, because you are only looking at the derivative matrix at one point.  Instead, I was thinking of writing something like $\| (D_{x_0}f)h  \| \leq \| (D_{x_0}f (h - h_{n_k}) \| + \| (D_{x_0}f)h_{n_k} \| \leq \| D_{x_0}f \| \| h - h_{n_k} \| + \| (D_{x_0} f )h_{n_k} \|$.  (Here, $ \| D_{x_0}f \|$ refers to the matrix norm.)  The term $\| (D_{x_0} f )h_{n_k} \|$ can be made small by your work.  The other term goes to zero because $h_{n_k} \to h$.

Comment: I see. Nice attempt!